# Running different Initial view controllers in app delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to show a tour for the first time my app starts.

Definitely I will use some `NSUserDefaults`. however I am using `storyboards` and I want to to load different `viewControllers` to load.

```
if(firstTime)
Load TourController 
else
Load mainScreen
```

How can I implement this in `appdelegate`?

Comment: Your question is not related to Xcode. Please use tags appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have different behaviour on the first launch in my app, but I didn't implement it in the app delegate. I used code in the delegate to keep track of the number of launches. Then, since the main view controller needs to be at the top of the view tree, I pushed the 1st launch behaviour modally from there.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    // the following forces new behaviour on 1st launch. 
    int launches;
    launches = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:LAUNCH_NUMBER_KEY];
    // note: uninitialised user default returns 0.

    if (!launches) {
        // view did load will check again and push the first load tour. 
        // by returning here, the launch value is not incremented. 
        [self.viewController viewDidLoad];
        return;
    } 
}
```

Then, in `MainViewController viewDidLoad`, I check the value again and push a firstLoad view modally.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //... more code here.
    BOOL disclaimerAccepted = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:DISCLAIMER_ACCEPT_KEY];
    if (!disclaimerAccepted) {
    [self showFirstLoadView];
    return;
    }
}
```

and

```
-(void) showDisclaimerView {

    // Display the nav controller modally.
    FirstLoadVC *firstLoadVC = [[FirstLoadVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstload" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [firstLoadVC autorelease];

    UINavigationController*  firstLoadNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstLoadVC]; 

    [self presentModalViewController:firstLoadNavController animated:YES];

    [firstLoadNavController release];
}
```

Comment: did i forgot to mention that i am using storyboards? :) I am using storyboards. I can't set two initial view controllers. that's the question i AM ASKING

Comment: Ahhh. Have you created viewController classes and connected them to your views in the storyboard at all? There's a good tutorial at [http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2]. Storyboards are a shortcut in writing code, but the code above should still be a way of doing this. You would modify the mainController as above and do a segue to the tourController in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: tHE Main thing i want is, i have two viewControllers. One is automatically set as initial view Controller i-e mainController. I want to show Tour controller as initial viewCOntroller once the app is installed. In other words I want to set programatically initial viewController

Comment: Sorry My english maybe bad that I can't explain enough

Comment: You have 2 view controllers. Are they only in storyboards? or do you have Objective-C classes for them as well?

Comment: Yes they are in made in storyboard. One has a class attached to it, one haven't got because its a Tour Controller. B

Answer (score 1):

```
if (firstTime) {
   self.window.rootViewController = self.fisrtController; 
} else {
   self.window.rootViewController = self.mainController;
}
```

Comment: This looks much cleaner, but how do you return control to mainController when firstController is finished?

Comment: i AM Using storyboards. It has an INITIAL View controller set to mainController